How to determine the Optimal Approach for Inserting Multiple Elements into a Binary Heap?
I have a max binary heap implemented based on a complete binary tree. I need to insert multiple elements into the heap, where the current heap array has a length of n and the new elements array has a length of m.
I have two methods to consider:
1.Merge the new elements array directly with the heap array and then perform Floyd's heap construction, which has a time complexity of O(m+n).
2.Insert each new element one by one into the heap, which results in a time complexity proportional to log(n) + log(n+1) + ... + log(n+m).
When m is small, the second method is preferable, but when m is large, the first method is more efficient.
How can I determine a threshold or critical point to decide which method to use?

Simply stated, the time complexity for adding elements one-by-one is (m log n).

My recommendation is that you create the first version of the program so that it always uses your method 2: add the m elements to the heap one at a time. Several reasons:

It's dead simple to implement.
It's dead simple to prove correct.
It's probably fast enough.

Implementing method 1 at this point is a classic case of premature optimization. Get your code working, make sure everything else is correct, and don't even think about the potential optimization unless profiling shows that adding items to the heap really is a bottleneck. Only then should you write code to do the merge-and-heapify. As you say, you'll have to define the threshold for determining which method to use. In theory, you want the point where:
(m+n) == m log n

So, let's see. Divide by m:
(m+n)/m = log n
m/m + n/m = log n
1 + n/m = log n
(drop the 1 to simplify)
n/m = log n
1/m = (log n)/n
m = n/log n

So, in theory, you're better off with method 1 up to the point where m is equal to n/log n. So if your heap has 1,000,000 items in it, you're better off with method 2 until m is 60,000 (assuming log base 2).
That's the theory, assuming the worst case behavior of the heap (i.e. O(log n)  insertion), and assuming that you can actually do meaningful arithmetic on computational complexities (which you really can't, in general, but we're ballparking the figures here). In practice, the average case of heap insertion is O(1), although the constant is somewhat higher than for heapify.
Anyway, you can derive a more realistic number by creating a heap with a million items. Time adding 500,000 items to the heap with method 1. Time adding the same items to the heap using method 2. If method 1 is faster, time adding 250,000 items. Basically, do a binary search looking for the largest number for which method 2 is faster than method 1.
(Note that you'll have to use some judgement here: it's likely that you'll get to a point where sometimes adding x items with method 1 is faster, but adding x+5 is faster with method 2. This will vary depending on the order in which things are inserted. You'll have to use your judgment to decide which method to favor in that grey area.)
Whether this exercise is worthwhile is going to depend on the size of your heap, the average number of items you add at any time, how fast you need the code to be, and probably a few other factors. As I recall, adding a million items to a binary heap doesn't take very long. heapify will be faster, but faster enough? You have to balance that against the time to implement (including the time you spend figuring out what the threshold value should be), thorough testing, and the added maintenance cost of the additional, more complex, code.
